# Can we pass multiple signers in invoke_signed?

Tags: anchor

As the title says, can we pass multiple signers in `invoke_signed()`?

Comment: please add a code example of what you've tried that didn't work or link to whatever documentation you're referencing and explain why it leads you to believe this isn't possible

Comment: thanks! please come back in two days to accept it then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so it is possible to pass multiple signers in `invoke_signed()`.

Example code:

```
invoke_signed(
    &Instruction,
    account_infos.as_slice(),
    // Multiple Signers
    &[
        &[ "PDA1_SEED1".as_bytes(), "PDA1_SEED2".as_bytes(), &[PDA1_bump] ], // first seed
        &[ "PDA2_SEED1".as_bytes(), "PDA2_SEED2".as_bytes(), &[PDA2_bump] ], // second seed

    ],
)?;
```

Comment: I think this represents signing for multiple different PDAs but critically, both PDAs in this case must be under the single authority of the program that calls `invoke_signed`.  The documentation indicates "the runtime will re-derive the PDA from the seeds **and the calling program’s ID**" when checking for a signature. This makes it possible to sign multiple accounts, but only as the same entity... right?

Comment: depends on your definition of "entity". as I stated in [my comment](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/1002/can-we-pass-multiple-signers-in-invoke-signed?noredirect=1#comment1056_1004) to your answer, multiple "entities" could sign the transaction, which the program then verifies and invokes some other program with corresponding PDAs for each.  The program effectively "approves" the CPI.

Answer (score 1):

Well **no**, but actually **yes**.

The call to [invoke_signed](https://docs.rs/solana-program/latest/solana_program/program/fn.invoke_signed.html) is only designed to generate signatures for program derived accounts (PDAs) that correspond directly to your program's deployed ID. You can sign multiple PDAs but you can't represent multiple different *signing entities*.

Programs can make use of [signature extension](https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/calling-between-programs#instructions-that-require-privileges) however to pass signatures previously provided by another entity along to subsequent programs. This means whatever signatures were provided when your program was loaded and executed are considered to remain signed when you use invoke_signed. So *if* you need additional *parties* to provide signatures, they should be added to the instruction that calls your program. Then they will be passed through to invoke_signed. They cannot be added *within* your program.

Comment: it really depends on the program's logic. several independent authorities could sign a transaction and the program logic pass seeds referencing each to `invoke_signed`, promoting their corresponding PDA to signers. i believe the answer is simply, "yes"

Comment: I think we're in agreement here. I avoided the simple "yes" just to make clear the distinction between adding a new program-generated "signature" (which `invoke_signed` can do for _only_ the calling program) and passing previous signatures/signers _through_ the same call.

Comment: right, but the program can cosign for unlimited (within the tx size limit) other authorities via PDA.  it's all up to the logic it implements.  which is why I suggest the answer is in fact "simple yes"

Comment: the program can also pass unlimited (within the tx size limit) other signatures through `invoke` without adding any endorsement. The _purpose_ of choosing `invoke_signed` though is to introduce co-signing and in that capacity, the program can represent only one _signer_. The semantic distinction between a _signature_ and a _signer_ here, although admittedly a little nit-picky, seems relevant to the context of this question.